# Cannot connect to TeamSpeak3 server with GameQ library

Tags: php

I'm using GameQ library to fetch data about my servers. Everything works except TeamSpeak3 server. I set type, host and in options array I provide query port. But when I try to connect I'm getting an error 'The server did not respond within the specified time'. I tried to set higher value of timeout but no effect.

My code which I use to add the server:

```
<?php
// Include the main class file
require '../GameQ.php';

// Define your servers,
// see list.php for all supported games and identifiers.


// Call the class, and add your servers.
$gq = new GameQ();
$gq->addServer(array(
        'type' => 'teamspeak3',
        'host' => '178.217.184.133',
        'options' => array(
                'master_server_port' => 25224,
                ),
));

// You can optionally specify some settings
$gq->setOption('timeout', 10); // Seconds

// You can optionally specify some output filters,
// these will be applied to the results obtained.
$gq->setFilter('normalise');

// Send requests, and parse the data
$results = $gq->requestData();
```

Rest of code is just an output code.

Comment: Can you connect manually to that service?

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean manual connect to the server via official client, I can.

Comment: Assuming the IP/port in your post is correct, telnetting to it from the command line did not work: `telnet 178.217.x.x 25224` -- it responded with `telnet: connect to address 178.217.x.x: Connection refused`.